# Fastest way to pull getTable() Recipient Email Addresses in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, search, outlook

I have found a few sources on here about individuals trying to get recipient information from a getTable() result and one of the sources pointed to a microsoft forum which the MVP indicates a potential solution but didnt expand on it all. My current code is as follows:

```
    Set MyTable = MySearch.GetTable
MyTable.Columns.Add ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E03001E")

Do Until MyTable.EndOfTable
    Set nextRow = MyTable.GetNextRow()
    For Each OutRecip In Session.GetItemFromID(nextRow("EntryID")).Recipients
        OutRecip.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E")
    Next
Loop
```

Currently I have to pull the entry id then find the mail item and then get the recipient list from it. I find it slow and was hoping for a faster method considering I am using the advance search function which the point is to be efficient. Is there any schema property which has the to, cc, and bcc in which I can extract somehow with a text function of some sort in vba?

Answer (score 2):

Recipient information cannot be pulled from a MAPI table. The best you can do is `PR_DISPLAY_TO` / `PR_DISPLAY_CC` / `PR_DISPLAY_BCC`, but these message properties do not (in general) contain email addresses or entry ids.

You can create search conditions based on the recipient properties, but you'd need Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (any language - I am its author) for that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but those options dont include the email addresses and unfortunatley I dont have any of those extras you mentioned :( . I did find one method which might work actually though using "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F" . This includes the from and to in list format which could allow extracting the values needed since their delimited. I would note though that the bcc does not seem to be included. Also, is there not a header for emails you send? I try to pull this property from my sent box and it doesnt return anything.

Comment: PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS is only available on the *received* messages, that is why you do not see it in the Sent Items folder. Take a look at the messages with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button).

Comment: I am going to give redemption a try but unfortunately our computers are locked down pretty tight so we cannot install any software. Can I download these dll's and just reference them from the vbe editor and then create object?

Comment: You can copy redemption.dll to any folder and register it using regsvr32.exe. It can install itself in HKCU if there is no write access to HKCR.

Comment: To create a restriction in Redemption, you can use Recipients / To / CC / BCC properties in a SQL statement used by RDOItems.Find or Restrict. It will use the specified value to match against PR_DISPLAY_NAME / PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS / PR_SMTP_ADDRESS recipient properties.

Comment: How does it install itself in HKCU if there is no write access? Just want to know before trying this due to the strict security settings in our environment.

Comment: It installs itself on per-user (HKCU hive) rather than machine-wide (HKCR hive) basis if the current user does not have elevated privileges.

Comment: Can it be removed from the HKCU hive easily also and if so how? Thanks as usual!

Comment: Does redemption also allow to suppress security warnings for non MAPI properties such as the outlook model objects like mailitem.body , mailitem.senderemailaddress

Comment: Of course - that was the primary reason why it was created almost 20 years ago. Redemption never raises any security prompts, only OOM does.

Comment: See I am basically using an excel application that communicates with outlook. All users use the same vb script to open the excel application in read only and the user form initiated. If I am goin to try and use redemption I need to figure out a way to programmatically add redemption either from the vbscript or from inside vba. I’d prefer the vba as when closing the form I want to remove redemption. Does this seem feasible or even logical for that matter? Security is a bit strict here hence all the questions.

Comment: Since you have more outlook experience I’m sure this issue has really come across you a bunch. So with some strong programming in the windows api should it be possible to accurately find that button to initiate?. Since that message text remains always I was thinking narrowing down that hwnd for the button may be possible to autopress when available.

Comment: Which button? The security prompt?

Comment: Yea the allow access checkbox then the allow button. I would think using windows API you could capture the handler of these and initiate them right?

Comment: You probably can - there is a product that does this: https://www.contextmagic.com/express-clickyes/ . But the button is disabled for a few seconds and the prompt cannot be immediately dismissed.

Comment: So I decided to give redemption a try for this. I added the redemption.dll file to a folder then went to references in the vba editor window and browsed for it and added it. However when I create the redemption object i get a "ActiveX component cannot create object" error. I checked that excel vba its running in is 32bit and so is my outlook. Any ideas why it would do that?

Comment: Have you tried to register the dll with regsvr32.exe?