# In MS Outlook VBA, why is not(PR_HASATTACH) always true and how to deal with that?

Tags: vba, outlook

In my question, *In MS Outlook VBA, why is looping through a table five times faster than looping through the folder?*, in the accepted [answer by Dmitry Streblechenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326024/in-ms-outlook-vba-why-is-looping-through-a-table-five-times-faster-than-looping/#76326193), he made a comment that to efficiently include the count of attachments in the output from a table, I should first test for `PR_HASATTACH` being true, and only if not, do the slow access of `MailItem.attachments.count`. I implemented that suggestion with the following code:

```
nAttachments = iif(not(oTableRow("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B")), 0, _
                   Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(oTableRow("EntryID")).Attachments.Count)
```

There are two problems with that. One is that it did not improve the efficiency because [VBA's `iif()` stupidly evaluates both conditions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function) But the worse problem is that the value of the above code is always zero because

```
not(oTableRow("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B"))
```

is mysteriously always true.

Why is that? And how do I fix the code? (I am posting this question in order to post the answer that I've found.)

Comment: what does `oTableRow("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B")` evaluate to? http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B doesn't seem to go anywhere if I type into google. Maybe the schema has moved? Also `NOT` is not a function `not()` but an operator without brackets e.g. `NOT oTableRow("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B")`. If oTableRow returns an integer like 1 or 0, then NOT does a bitwise not rather than logical. So you need to check `oTableRow = 0` rather than `NOT oTableRow`

Comment: `Iif()` is a function in vba so it makes sense it evaluates both arguments, consistent with other functions like `Max(a,b)`. There is no ternary operator in vba sadly.

Comment: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B" is the "DASL name" of `PR_HASATTACH`. Sorry, I don't completely understand that. See a comment by Dmitry Streblechenko saying so at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76268753/how-to-add-a-table-column-for-an-object-property/#76273756

Comment: In my coding style, I put optional parens around the argument of `not` because it makes the code easier to read, as well as for potential compatibility with other languages in which `not` is a function. Sorry if you disagree or don't like that style, but it's not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that VBA and MAPI use different definitions of the data type `Boolean`.

|  | True | False |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VBA | -1 | 0 |
| MAPI | 1 | 0 |

For VBA, the documentation [*Boolean Data Type (Visual Basic)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/boolean-data-type) states that "When Visual Basic converts Boolean values to numeric types, False becomes 0 and True becomes -1."

For MAPI, `PR_HASATTACH`  is the associated property of the MAPI property [`PidTagHasAttachments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtaghasattachments-canonical-property), whose documentation at that link says that it has data type [`PT_BOOLEAN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-oshared/bfed9f7b-80e2-4683-b8aa-e31c269edc37), whose documentation at that link links to [*[MS-OXCDATA]: Data Structures*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/MS-OXCDATA/), which links to a [pdf specification document](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-OXCDATA/%5BMS-OXCDATA%5D.pdf), which states on page 90 that `PT_BOOLEAN` is "1 byte; restricted to 1 or 0" and on page 95 that "The Unicode value of the element is interpreted as a Boolean value either "1" (TRUE) or "0" (FALSE)."

VBA's [documentation of `not()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/not-operator) does not explain the problems that can arise from such inconsitent definitions of `true`, but there has been extensive [discussion of it on *StackOverflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59310779/vba-why-would-the-not-operator-stop-working). In all of that discussion, I don't see any correct workaround, but there is a very simple one:

```
not(A) ==> (A = 0)
```

In my case, I was only using the `not()` to make the `iif()` code easier to read. Since I needed to get rid of `iif()` anyway, the simpler solution for me was simply to also drop the `not()`. With that, the code in the question transforms to:

```
If (oTableRow("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B")) Then
    nAttachments = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(oTableRow("EntryID")).Attachments.Count
  Else
    nAttachments = 0
  End If
```

Using that code, I got the correct attachment count in my results with the reduction in speed from 5 seconds per thousand items to 8 seconds, which is an acceptable cost of getting that count and is a lot better than the 29 seconds per thousand (34 items/second) that it took to loop through the folder instead of the table.